# jQuery Dialog leaving page on getScript() call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following jQueryUI Dialog element.. I'm trying to make an AJAX call to populate the form when it launches.. I'm also using Ajax to load the actual form..

Problem happens when the populateForm method is invoked..

The Dialog disappears and the browser leaves my page when the $.getScript method is invoked..

any ideas?

I'm stuck!

DIALOG

```
$('#highValueSurvey').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            resizable: false,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $("#highValueSurvey").load('/longstoryshort/forms/high.html');
                $("#highValueSurvey").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                populateForm('#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm');
            },
            buttons: {
                'Submit': function() {
                    var path = $(this).data('link').href; // Get the stored result
                    doAjaxPost('#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm');
                    setCookie(highValueCookieName, -1, 1000);
                    window.location.href = path;
                }
            }
        });
```

CLICK EVENT

```
$("a.clickHighValueAsset").click(function(e) {
    cookie_value = getCookie(highValueCookieName);
    if (cookie_value != -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#highValueSurvey")
                .data('link', this)// bind the url from the HREF to the dialog UI for redirect later
                .dialog('open');
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

POPULATE METHOD

```
function populateForm(formName) {
    if (typeof eMail != 'undefined') {
        elqServlet = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/longstoryshort/forms/lookup.jsp?email=';
        $.getScript(elqServlet + eMail, function() {
            $(':input', '#' + formName).each(function() {
                var field = '#' + this.name + '';
                $(field).val(GetElqContentPersonalizationValue(this.name));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the populateForm() which is async.. And then call the window.href redirect within it's success callback!

Example:

```
            'Submit': function() {
                $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: true,
                            url:  $("#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm").attr('action'),
                            data: $("#FY12-Q1-AM-ALL-ECMC-VML-ProfilingForm").serialize()
                        });
                setCookie(highValueCookieName, -1, 1000);
                $(":button:contains('Submit')").hide();
                $("#highValueSurvey").load('/longstoryshort/forms/confirmation.html');
                $("#highValueSurvey").dialog({
                            close: function() {
                                var path = $(this).data('link').href; // Get the stored result
                                window.location.href = path;
                            }
                        });
            }
```